# In 1980, he designed a radio which (was/is) made with old tin can : which is right? was?is?

Tags: verbs

the radio in the context is still being made(in africa)
so i thought 'is' should come,
but my friend told me to use 'was'

which is right? i'm confused

Comment: @NigelJ "... made with *an* old tin can"

Comment: @HotLicks (2nd attempt) 'He designed a radio made with an old tin can'. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the word "was" (i.e. the past tense) because the sentence is referring to something that happened in 1980, the design of the radio. You would not use "is" (i.e. the present tense), because the sentence is not referring to what is still happening in the present, the manufacturing of the radio.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to convey that both the design and manufacture occurred in the past, then used the past tense for both verbs.

if, however, you wanted to convey that the manufacture was still ongoing, then explicitly state that:

*In 1980, he designed a radio which was made with an old tin can.  It is still being made in this way.*

This should avoid confusion on the reader's part.

Comment: You need _**an** old tin can._

Comment: @KarlG  You are correct!..............I will correct the answer